# Notepad++ making new file counter out of the session

Tags: notepad++

I would like to know if it's possible to set up notepad++ in order to remember the number of files created like "new 22", even if starting a new session.

I don't want to open notepad++ and find "New 1" after i close all documents, i would like an always incrementing system, no matter of the folder or the session.

Is this possible?

Comment: I bet this gets closed as off topic. It shouldn't do though.